# How did I ruin my MikTeX installation and how can I fix this?

Tags: miktex

Today, I started the MikTeX update program because I needed a newer version of some library.  It first wanted to update the base installation and at some point it complained that it couldn't replace some library/DLL, which obviously happened because I still had an instance of pdflatex running somewhere.  (Unfortunately, I forgot which library it was...)  The only option I had at that point was to cancel the update.

I now have the problem that latexmk doesn't work anymore.  I can still use TeXworks and so on, but whenever I use `latexmk -pvc -pdf`, I get

```
Can't spawn "pdflatex  -recorder  "test.tex"": No error at ...
...
pdflatex: Command for 'pdflatex' gave return code 65280
```

If I try to call `pdflatex -recorder` manually, I get a segmentation fault.

So, I completely removed MikTeX and reinstalled it using the current installer from the MikTeX web site.  Still the same problem...

Then I completely removed MiKTeX again and in a desperate effort installed the 32-bit version of MiKTeX (instead of the 64-bit version I had used before).  Still the same problem...

Any idea what to do or at least how to debug the problem?  I can still use MiKTeX, but I've come to rely on latexmk and right now, with a pending deadline, this is pretty much the worst that could happen... :(

**Added:**

Below is a screen shot which shows how a Windows error box pops up.  It also shows (in the console window) the last part of running `pdflatex` without the `-recorder` option, which worked fine.

[Screen Shot http://miles.agharta.de/screen.png](http://miles.agharta.de/screen.png)

Comment: To be clear: if you run `pdflatex <filename>` from the Command Prompt all is well, but if you run `pdflatex --recorder <filename>` in the same place and for the same file it goes wrong. Correct? Assuming that is the case, can we have a screen shot of the error?

Comment: That is correct, yes.  I'll add a screen shot.

Comment: Testing with a 'clean' system I get an error with `pdflatex -recorder`. I suspect there's an issue with the MiKTeX binaries, which would explain why a clean install doesn't help. That can only be fixed by Christian Schenk: report on the MiKTeX mailing list.

Comment: `recorder` fails for me too and I will make a bug report. And: next time you get a problem don't get in an installation frenzy. Stop and think.

Comment: I'm faced with similar problem. After upgrade MikTeX with recent version I have the problems with compiling LateX files with require packages with Python support (mdframed, tcolorbox withd libraries used minted, minted, animate etc). What to do? I will wait to next upgrade of MikTeX with hope, that meantime this problem will be resolved ... and mean time use my old PC with old MikTeX installation, which still works (lucky me).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is solved by an update ...